# vmxnet NIC not usable

Tags: hyper-v, vmware-esx, dell

I have a Dell Edge 860 Xeon server running ESXi40 hyperV. Ive created a linux VM with VMXNET adaptor. I'm able to bring the interface up but it is not able to ping default gw or any machine on the subnet for that matter. Its pinging only itself. With i add another flexible interface to the VM and reboot, even if i dont assign an IP address or bring this new flexible interface up, the VMXNET interface starts working and is able to ping the subnet ?

Im not sure about this behavior, once i remove the flexible adaptor the VMXNET interface stops working. Need help

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your Hyper-V reference and tag - what part does that play?

So you have a VM with a vNIC that's not pinging it's DG, you add a second vNIC and the first suddenly can ping its DG - is that right?

If that's the case then we'll need to know the exact details on the Linux you're running, also have you installed the 'vmtools'? Also are you SURE that when you add the second vNIC that the ping traffic goes over the first vNIC? it's just that to me it sounds like you've created your first vNIC with the VMXNET adapter but perhaps not installed the vmtools, this won't work correctly so you add the flexible second vNIC which when faced with a vmtool-less VM reverts back to E1000 mode with IS supported by most Linux versions at which point it sounds like it's picking up the IP setting for the first vNIC which will then work, you remove the flexible second vNIC at which point it stops working. That's my best guss right now but it would be great to get these details from you.